# Are the Studio Ghibli films on HBO Max uncut?

Tags: alternate-version, anime

Are the Studio Ghibli films recently made available for streaming on HBO Max uncut?

Comment: I'm reminded of the anecdote about how Harvey Weinstein wanted to cut 45 minutes out of *Princess Mononoke* for its original US release, and Hayao Miyazaki sent him a katana with "no cuts" engraved into the blade. The film was released uncut.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not so much a question about understanding or appreciating a work, than it is a platform support question... Which this site isn't about, IMO

Comment: @Jenayah wow, you are on one today. Can anyone ask a question you don’t want to close? This is a perfectly valid question, not unlike others that have been asked.

Comment: @Darren Normally I'm fine with closing when it makes sense, but in this case the question, to be properly answered, really requires a lot of expertise that will only be found here: to reliably answer it, I'm not interested in what HBO says, but what people who know the films intimately can share about the versions HBO is streaming.

Comment: @Darren Frankly, *you're* "on one" today, too. This question has *nothing* to do with the other question and I'd ask *you* to calm down a bit, too, especially when looking at the tone of your comments. Let's not lose sight of the forest for the trees, please and generalize individual mistakes more than necessary.

Comment: As to the question, I'm afraid this indeed comes down to a support question about HBO Max, which really isn't the domain of this site. Unless this can be rephrased into a more general direction that isn't just asking what version of a film a specific TV-channel is showing, it doesn't seem on-topic here.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: How about "What versions of Studio Ghibli films is HBO streaming?" or "Where are uncut versions of Studio Ghibli films available?"

Comment: The second one would be classified a shopping question, which is definitely off-topic here, The first one sounds acceptable, but *maybe* a bit broad, considering how many Ghibli films there are.

Comment: @orome The former is pretty much the same kind of support question and the latter is akin to asking where to watch content, neither of which is really what we do on this site, I'm afraid. I understand you want to find that out, but doesn't the HBO Max documentation help with that to some degree? What does the runtime comparison say?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson No, the two questions are not related with the exception that I am confident I can find variations of both that have been left open and answered, are both valid IMO and are both being leapt on by trigger happy VTCers that spoils the welcome new users to this site receive and goes against the successful building of a community. If that is what is trying to be achieved here.

Comment: @Darren And as long as you don't stumble over your own mouth or make it about specific people, you have a right for that critique.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Runtime won't do it. To answer the question (clearer now I hope with one of the alternates) I need to hear from people who have (a) actually know how to identify versions of SG films and (b) have examined the HBO offerings closely enough to know what versions it is streaming.

Comment: If comparing runtime isn't enough (presumably because the runtime is the same), then what is the reason you're *expecting* them to show cut versions in the first place? Maybe investigating that more specifically than just looking at HBO would be closer to solving the real problem, too.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Hmm, now if lost you. Anyway. I didn't mean to stir up such a discussion. I guess there are some modding issues here that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: What about a more general question about cut versions of these films in general? "Do there exist edited/cut versions of Studio Ghibli films"?